# Microsoft Data Link | Oracle database name conflicting with domain name(?)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oraoledb

I am addressing a peculiar issue with "Net Service Name" somehow causing an unrelated issue while testing a newly created connection using OraOLEDB. Our legacy database name is same as our domain name (the domain was designed and implemented much later after the database came in to production)

This is how the Oracle Net Service Name is defined:

```
KAZEMA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.200)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = KAZEMA)
    )
  )
```

and our internal domain is `KAZEMA.COM`. If I try to create a UDL file for ORACLE connection referring the Net Service Name as `KAZEMA`, I get a TNS timeout error & a minor change to the Net Service Name like `KAZEMA1` establishes the connection without any complaints. However, other than the UDL, this Net Service Name is not affecting any other connection attempts (so far) from VS or SSMA etc.

I pry some explanations towards this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apologies for my previous comment, which was NOT tested twice prior posting. I've found the "issues" by enabling the tracing on connection attempts.
I've had a copy of the tnsnames.ora files on my \user\desktop & for reasons unknown to me, the .udl file was using the copy of tnsnames.ora as local file while trying to establish the connection.

```
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nnftmlf_make_local_addrfile:local names file is C:\Users\rthampi\Desktop\tnsnames.ora
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nnftmlf_make_local_addrfile:exit
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nlpaxini:entry
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nlpaxini:exit
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile:entry
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile:system names file is D:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile:exit
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nnftboot:exit
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nnftrne:entry
2018-12-09 17:23:51.970 : nnftrne:Original name: KAZEMA
```

This copy of tnsnames.ora has the same Net Service Name with a different IP address, thus causing the TNS timeout errors.